# Issue with loading data from ISLR package

Tags: r

I am an R newbie and currently looking at the book **An Introduction to
Statistical Learning with Applications in R**. For many of their examples they use the package `ISLR`. Unfortunately, I struggle with an example: They install the package (I have tried it in R and RStudio) and execute the following code

```
Auto=read.table("Auto.data")
```

When I do that, I get the following error message:

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In file(file, "rt") :
>     cannot open file 'Auto.data': No such file or directory

I also tried to attach the package with the command `library(ISLR)` after downloading it - without success. I am not sure if the issue is related to the path of the package but I don't believe so. At least I tried to save the package in my working directory.

I feel a bit stupid as the task looks more than easy. If anyone could help out, it would be much appreciated. Everything related (including a PDF of the book can be found [HERE](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/)

Comment: *"I also tried to attach the package with the command `library(ISLR)` after downloading it - without success"*... not much detail here. Install the package once `install.packages("ISLR")`, then load the package every R session `library(ISLR)`. If it "doesn't work", provide details.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just use

```
library(ISLR)
```

Then the `Auto` dataset becomes immediately available:

```
> head(Auto)
  mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration year origin                      name
1  18         8          307        130   3504         12.0   70      1 chevrolet chevelle malibu
2  15         8          350        165   3693         11.5   70      1         buick skylark 320
3  18         8          318        150   3436         11.0   70      1        plymouth satellite
4  16         8          304        150   3433         12.0   70      1             amc rebel sst
5  17         8          302        140   3449         10.5   70      1               ford torino
6  15         8          429        198   4341         10.0   70      1          ford galaxie 500
```

Please read the book carefully. This is an excerpt from page 48:

> We begin by loading in the Auto data set. This data is part of the
>   ISLR library (we discuss libraries in Chapter 3) but to illustrate the
>   read.table() function we load it now from a text file. The following
>   command will load **the Auto.data file** into R and store it as an object
>   called Auto , in a format referred to as a data frame. (**The text file
>   data frame can be obtained from this book’s website.**)

(Emphasis added).

Here is the link to the file that should be saved in the working directory:

http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Auto.data

Once the file is saved with the name `Auto.data` in the working directory, the command

```
Auto <- read.table("Auto.data")
```

should work without any problem.

Better results will be obtained using

```
Auto <- read.table("Auto.data", header=TRUE)
```

as described later in that book.

Comment: technically, although `Auto` is accessible, it's *not* in the global environment: `find("Auto")` returns `"package:ISLR"` (admittedly this distinction won't matter to a beginner)

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for pointing this out. I will rephrase that part.

Comment: Thx for your contribution. I saved the Auto file in the working directory and ran `Auto <- read.table("Auto.data")` but still got the message **Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'Auto.data': No such file or directory** Maybe I am overlooking something.. the first part worked btw.

Comment: @MarkusKnopfler In an R console, try to type `"Auto.data" %in% list.files()` if the output is `FALSE`, you are either not in the right directory (this can be checked with `getwd()`) or the file is not stored with the name `Auto.data`.

Comment: You may even load the file directly from the web: `Auto <- read.table("http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/Auto.data", header=TRUE)`

Comment: @RHertel In the end everything you worked (still don't understand it didnt in the first place). Anyway, many thanks for your help!!!

Comment: @MarkusKnopfler If my answer has helped in solving your problem, please consider [accepting it by clicking on the tick on the left](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234).

Comment: Wasn't aware of that functionality. Of course more than happy to do that! Cheers again!

Answer (score 4):

Install ISLR via `install.packages("ISLR")` and execute:

```
library(ISLR)
auto_df = ISLR::Auto
```

I now have access to the auto dataset, e.g.

```
auto_df[1,]

    mpg cylinders displacement horsepower weight acceleration ...
1   18  8         307          130        3504   12           ...
```

Answer (score 2):

The data download location has changed. You can find Auto.data and similar files at:
https://www.statlearning.com/resources-first-edition
Download the file that you need and move it to your working directory. Then use the command that you were using originally:

```
Auto=read.table("Auto.data")
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the best thing to do is to:
1. download the data package from this link https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ISLR/index.html
2. in R studio under the menu packages, select Package Archive File and browse to where the download is.
3. press install

Answer (score 0):

Download the data set from the internet, which is "Auto.data". Then copy it to your current working directory. Next, you need to set the directory from:
Session->Set Working Directory->Choose Directory (choose it to your current directory). After that, follow the instruction:

```
Auto=read.table("Auto.data")
```

Answer (score 0):

On Windows OS, the file is saved with .txt extension by default. Using list.files() in R confirms this. Save the file with .data extention, then it works.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was an issue of opening the data file directory first

so i had this line first (this is where i saved the 'Auto.data' file at), then it works in reading the data

setwd("~/Codings/R")

Answer (score 0):

link for download data is: http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/data.html place the file in your working directory then you can read.table()

Answer (score 0):

I also cope with the same problem and have solved it. So I reach the conclusion below, pls correct me if I am wrong (since I am almost a newbie, as well)

It seems that there are two ways to read data: (1) download it and save it in your working folder, then call it or download it directly from the internet (2) when working with a package (i.e. ISLR), once you have loaded the ISLR package with the “library” command, you do not need to use the “read.table” command to load the “Auto” data. It is already loaded in R. So we can view the file using fix(Auto).

The example script (corresponding to what I mentioned above)

(1) If you downloaded if save file Auto in your computer already

`setwd("direction to the downloaded data")`

`Auto <-read.table("Auto.data")`

(2) If not download the Auto file to your computer, instead of downloading the package ISLR

`install.package ("ISLR")`
`library(ISLR)`
`fix(Auto)`

I don't understand why that book "An Introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R" teaches us to read.data after installing ISLR, it makes me confused and makes the script doesn't work.

Comment: it is usually more helpful to add some code in there.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).